# (bash) Removing leading zeroes with a "v" right before said zeroes

Tags: bash, rename, leading-zero

First of all, I'm unable to use the "find" function, due to the files being .cbz, and recursing two layers deep would break them, thus, I'm left with only being able to recurse through one layer -- which is fine for my needs. I'm trying to do this on a mass scale with up to 1000 files being involved.

Currently:

```
Manga Name Here v004 - A Great Journey
Manga Name Here v053 - A Greater Journey
Manga Name Here v105 - The Best Journey
```

Expected

```
Manga Name Here, Volume 4 - A Great Journey
Manga Name Here, Volume 53 - A Greater Journey
Manga Name Here, Volume 105 - The Best Journey
```

I've attempted several methods, but.. I couldn't figure it out on my own. The main one that I'm trying that's failing is this.

`rename 's/ v0([1-9]+)/, Volume $1/e' *v*.cbz`

I don't quite get what I'm doing wrong, and I've tried more than "rename", but.. I couldn't figure out how to actually *rename it to that*, even if I got the leading zeroes gone. I appreciate any answers. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: You have 2 statements that I can't imagine what you mean by: a) "I'm unable to use the "find" function, due to the files being .cbz," and b) "recursing two layers deep would break them". Neither of those situations would be a reason not to use `find`. Also you say they're ".cbz" files but then under "Currently" none of the file names end in ".cbz" so idk what that means either.

Comment: All good ideas above, but I ask why you want to give up "naturally" sorting filenames? Note that when you do `ls "Manga Name Here"*`, you'll get `filev1, filev10, filev11, ..., filev100,... filev2, filev21, filev22, filev200, ...`  Maybe thats not true in a file browser/explorer? Good luck.

Comment: anyway for sure the regex has a fatal flaw since `v0([1-9]+)` won't surely match things like `v004` .. you should include the zero! so the character class should be `[0-9]` instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895) (usable in any OS):

```
rename -n 's/v(\d+)/sprintf "Volume %.1d", $1/e' ./*
```

remove `-n` when happy with the output.

Processed files:

```
'Manga Name Here Volume 105 - The Best Journey'
'Manga Name Here Volume 4 - A Great Journey'
'Manga Name Here Volume 53 - A Greater Journey'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I attempted that, but it did not seem to work (just now, based off of your comment)

Comment: Have you tried my command? It produces your exact expected output

Comment: I have, yes. For some reason, it's not working. I can't explain why, either. Like, by all logic and all that, it should, but it isn't.

Comment: I gave a link for different `rename` implementations, my bet is that you are using the wrong `rename` utility. Check it

Comment: That could very well be correct. I'm using NixOS, so I'll try to figure that out. My bad, if that was the issue.

Comment: Pretty sure it is this issue

Comment: Since by all logic it should work, and it's my end, I'll mark it as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you need is (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for old in *v*.cbz; do
    if [[ $old =~ (.* )v0*([1-9].*) ]]; then
        new="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}, Volume ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        echo mv -- "$old" "$new"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't figure out how to actually rename it to that, even if I got the leading zeroes gone.

> For some reason, it's not working. I can't explain why, either. Like, by all logic and all that, it should, but it isn't.

If you happen to be using the `rename` tool that is part of the `util-linux` package from the Linux Kernel Archive (see https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/), it has to be called as follows (see the [source](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/rename.c) and the [man page](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/rename.1.adoc)):

```bash
rename [options] expression replacement file...
```

Thus, calling this `rename` needs at least three arguments, and as `expression` and `replacement` are not treated as regex, for your "up to 1000 files" you'd need to call it up to three times, depending on how many `0`s could be prefixing your numbers (the fourth case for number `000` can be integrated into any other case). The `-n` flag induces a test run with no changes made, and the `-v` flag shows which files it would rename to what. Remove `-nv` if the test run output looks promising:

```bash
n="Manga Name Here"
rename -nv "$n v00" "$n, Volume " "$n"\ v00[0-9]\ -*.cbz
rename -nv "$n v0"  "$n, Volume " "$n"\ v0[1-9][0-9]\ -*.cbz
rename -nv "$n v"   "$n, Volume " "$n"\ v[1-9][0-9][0-9]\ -*.cbz
```

```
`Manga Name Here v004 - A Great Journey.cbz' -> `Manga Name Here, Volume 4 - A Great Journey.cbz'
`Manga Name Here v053 - A Greater Journey.cbz' -> `Manga Name Here, Volume 53 - A Greater Journey.cbz'
`Manga Name Here v105 - The Best Journey.cbz' -> `Manga Name Here, Volume 105 - The Best Journey.cbz'
```

---

> I'm unable to use the "find" function, due to the files being .cbz, and recursing two layers deep would break them

I don't quite understand why/how specifying the ending of a file name and/or facing a nested file tree would keep you from using `find`, but as far as this `rename` tool is concerned, let me hint you to the manual which further states:

> if either *expression* or *replacement* contains a */*, the full path is updated. This can cause a file to be moved between folders.